# How to get specific parameter from URL in php

Tags: php, url

I want to fetch method id from following URL,

I have used following code to get url

```
$s = empty($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? '' : ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "s" : "";
$protocol = strleft(strtolower($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]), "/").$s;
$port = ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] == "80") ? "" : (":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]);

$url = $protocol."://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$port.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Result:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/post-file.php?id=154&email=stevemartin144@ymail.com&method=2&reference=uhr748
```

I want to get method id from above URL i.e 2

Answer (score 0):

Use [superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) in this case [`$_GET`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php):

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

All your request data will be available in either `$_GET` or `$_POST`, you should not decompose the URL yourself. If however, you want to parse a URL, that is not the current request, use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_GET` like this

```
echo $_GET['id'];
```

Output of `var_dump($_GET);`

```
array (size=4)
  'id' => string '154' (length=3)
  'email' => string 'stevemartin144@ymail.com' (length=24)
  'method' => string '2' (length=1)
  'reference' => string 'uhr748' (length=6)
```

You can get other vars:

```
echo $_GET['email'];
echo $_GET['method'];
echo $_GET['reference'];
```